# Simple dom inspector script counts incorrectly child nodes

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have simple js function that returns me dom path to clicked element. However sometimes some element(usually the one i have clicked) counts twice

so if i have following code

```
<ul>
<li><a href ='#'>Some link</a></li>
</ul>
```

the output could be like `ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(2)`
while `a` should be 1 child.

Here is the code of function

```
var getDomPath;

getDomPath = function(el) {
  var count, element, nth, path, selector, sib;
  element = el;
  if (!(el instanceof Element)) {
    return;
  }
  path = [];
  while (el.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && el.id !== "jobs") {
    selector = el.nodeName.toLowerCase();
    if (el.id) {
      selector += "#" + el.id;
    } else if (el.className) {
      selector += "." + el.className;
    } else {
      sib = el;
      nth = 1;
      count = 1;
      while (sib.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && (sib = sib.previousSibling) && $(el).prev().prop('tagName') !== "STYLE" && $(el).prev().prop('tagName') !== null) {

        count += $(el).prevAll().size();
      }
      selector += ":nth-child(" + count + ")";
    }
    path.unshift(selector);
    el = el.parentNode;
  }
  return path.join(" > ");
};
```

Code was converted from coffee to javascript, so might looks a little bad

here is html that im trying to get path to

```
<td width="50%"><strong>Leveringssadresse</strong>
<br>
Hans Andersen
<br>
Andevej 123
<br>
1234 Andeby
<br>
Denmark
<br>
Telefon: 31122345
<br>
Mobiltelefon: 12232345
<br>
<a href="mailto:mail@gmail.com">mail@gmail.com</a>
<br>
</td>
```

Here when i click on `a` element i expect it to be `nth-child(8)`, but somehow i'm getting it 17(16 + 1 as increment by 1 in my code)

Comment: I guess ``Node.ELEMENT_NODE`` is defined correctly elsewhere?

Comment: its not defined anywhere, its named constant

Comment: It should be 9 in the example (*1 `strong` and 7 `br` + your 1*) and it is see http://jsfiddle.net/nAHBS/ (*open the console*)

Comment: it counts only previous elements, not all, so last br is being ignored, but i just have tested it on jsfiddle, and it seems to count even element after selected, which is wrong, and doesnt work on my local machine when i execute it on my page

Comment: You are aware that white space between tags (f.e. the line break between `</strong>` and the following `<br>` in your example HTML) creates text nodes in the DOM too …?

Comment: nth child is 1-indexed so shouldn't you expect it to return 9, not 8? I also got it working here http://jsbin.com/aGAwUDO/1/ in chrome, so it looks like it's either your browser or something else in your code that's causing the 17. Which jquery are you using?

Comment: @wheresrhys If you remove the line break from before the `a`, it does indeed say `17`. [Code](http://jsbin.com/IPeLOM/1/edit)

Comment: @Avdept there are 7 `br`  elements before the `a` and one `strong` element. That is 8, so the `a` is the 9th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
while (sib.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && (sib = sib.previousSibling) && $(el).prev().prop('tagName') !== "STYLE" && $(el).prev().prop('tagName') !== null) {
```

I have read this line multiple times, and I can't work out what you're trying to do.

Your code says:

- make sure that the currently examined node is an element
- set the currently examined node to be its previous sibling
- check that the element before the original node has a tag name that isn't `STYLE`

I have no idea what that sequence of steps is intended to be, but if the final condition passes, it will calculate `n * (x + 1) + 1`, where `n` is the number of preceding element siblings and `x` is the number of immediately preceding element siblings without intervening text nodes.

The next line is this:

```
count += $(el).prevAll().size();
```

This, surely, should only be run once, with the conditional not necessary at all.

```
count = $(el).prevAll().length + 1;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lonesomeday/BEUrn/1/) with working code.

Answer (score 2):

Just noticed you use jQuery.

Why not simplify it to just

```
function getDomPath(element){
    var path = $(element).parents().andSelf().map(function(){
        var index = $(this).index() + 1;
        return this.nodeName.toLowerCase() + ':nth-child('+ index +')';
    }).get();

  return path.join(' > ');
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/BEUrn/3/